# Decorative lines above and left of text

Tags: header-footer, fancyhdr, mdframed

I would like to recreate this decoration, which is being placed at the top of every page:

[image]

So a thin line above the text, and a thicker line left of the text. I've been trying to do this using the `mdframed` package, but I am not able to use a different width for the two lines. My question is: is the mdframed package the right way to go, or should I use something different?

If it's the right way to go, here's my code; how to differentiate between the width of the lines?

```
\newmdenv[rightline=false,bottomline=false,linewidth=2]{frameit}
...
\begin{frameit}
  Forum
\end{frameit}
```

I see no information about this in the manual: http://mirrors.ctan.org/macros/latex/contrib/mdframed/mdframed.pdf

Comment: And the text where does it come from? Is it always the same? Does it correspond to section titles?

Comment: @GonzaloMedina Text is always the same, it's on every page. It's a header you could say,  indicating what kind of document it is.

Comment: I see. Please see my answer below.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

To create headers/footers You could use either the [`titleps`](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/titleps) or the [`fancyhdr`](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/fancyhdr) package; a little example using `fancyhdr`:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[a5paper]{geometry}% just for the example
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\fancyhf{}
\setlength\headheight{13.7pt}
\renewcommand\headrulewidth{0pt}
\fancyhead[C]{\renewcommand\headrulewidth{.4pt}\headrule}
\fancyhead[L]{\rule[-2pt]{3pt}{10pt}\hspace*{0.5em}\sffamily\footnotesize\bfseries FORUM}
\fancyfoot[C]{\thepage}
\pagestyle{fancy}

\begin{document}

\lipsum[1-12]

\end{document}
```

[image]

Here's another possibility using this time the [`tikzpagenodes`](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/tikzpagenodes) and [`background`](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/background) packages:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[a5paper]{geometry}% just for the example
\usepackage{background}
\usepackage{tikzpagenodes}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\backgroundsetup{
  scale=1,
  angle=0,
  opacity=1,
  color =black,
  contents={\begin{tikzpicture}[remember picture,overlay]
    \draw ([yshift=18pt]current page text area.north west) -- 
      ([yshift=18pt]current page text area.north east);
    \draw[line width=3pt] ([yshift=18pt,xshift=0.5\pgflinewidth]current page text area.north west) -- 
      ++(0pt,-10pt);
    \node[anchor=west] at ([yshift=11pt,xshift=5pt]current page text area.north west) {\sffamily\bfseries\footnotesize FORUM};
    \end{tikzpicture}}
}
\begin{document}

\lipsum[1-12]

\end{document}
```

[image]

Of course, the [`mdframed`](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/mdframed) package can also be used here, but it seems somehow an overkill:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[a5paper]{geometry}% just for the example
\usepackage[framemethod=tikz]{mdframed}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\fancyhf{}
\setlength\headheight{29.2pt}
\renewcommand\headrulewidth{0pt}
\fancyhead[C]{\begin{mdframed}[
  skipabove=0pt,
  skipbelow=0pt,
  topline=true,
  leftline=true,
  rightline=false,
  bottomline=false,
  innerbottommargin=0pt,
  singleextra= {\draw[line width=3pt] (P-|O) -- (O);}]
\sffamily\footnotesize\bfseries FORUM
\end{mdframed}}
\fancyfoot[C]{\thepage}
\pagestyle{fancy}

\begin{document}

\lipsum[1-12]

\end{document}
```

The different width for the framing lines was achieved with the help of the `singleextra` command.

[image]

Comment: So when does `mdframed` package fit in ?

Comment: @texenthusiast no need to use `mdframed` here; of course it could be used, but seems an overkill.

Comment: @GonzaloMedina Thanks, all clear. I'll study the details of the fancyhead commands that created the decoration.

Comment: Just to confirm the tag changes and wondering whether it's possible, thats all. Thanks

Comment: @texenthusiast I can add a solution using `mdframed`, if you want to.

Comment: @GonzaloMedina you are a magic typesetting machine, Yes, as you like to bring life to tags and warn others not to use overkill. I am really a fan of your posts and style.

Comment: @texenthusiast code with `mdframed` added.

Comment: @user I added two more options to my answer; the third one using `mdframed` and showing how to get different width for the lines; this option, however (and possibly also the second one), might be an overkill.

Comment: @texenthusiast You're welcome. Thank you for your kind words.

Comment: @GonzaloMedina I am learning from examples here. `infinite patience` is seen most of the times here.

Comment: @GonzaloMedina Wow, amazing to see all these options! I'll study them to see that is going on - and for now I'll use the `fancyhdr` option which I already have implemented and which is working just fine!